# What size should I maintain for %rsp when alloc stack in asm, multiple of 16 or multiple of 16 plus 8

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

In this answer [Segmentation fault on printf - NASM 64bit Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693827/segmentation-fault-on-printf-nasm-64bit-linux) the first author says when I allock stack  the %rsp must keep multiple of 16 plus 8 because afterwards a function call will push address on stack  , But In ABI ,it says rsp must be multiple of 16 in program entry, And When I really try I found keep rsp multiple of 16 plus 8 cause segmentation fault even when then I call printf@PLT afterwards,but Keep it multiple of 16 works, So what should I do for rsp when alloc stack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But In ABI ,it says rsp must be multiple of 16 in program entry

**`_start` is not a function.**  It's not `call`ed by anything, there is no return address on the stack (just `argc` and the actual `argv[]` and `envp[]` arrays).

Yes, on *process* entry RSP is already 16-byte aligned, ready for a function call.

---

I edited Jester's answer again on the question you linked to clarify it.

16-byte aligned *before* a `call` is the requirement.  You get back to that with an offset of `16 * n + 8` inside your function before another call, including any `push`es.